# Recover corrupted external hard drive on Mac OS

Tags: macos, hard-drive, partitioning, data-recovery, filesystem-corruption

I have a Western Digital My Passport 4TB hard drive which has recently become corrupted. The hard drive is neither able to mount, nor does it show up on Disk Utility (of Mac OS) or third-party data recovery tools (iBoysoft, DiskDrill, etc.). The hard drive was originally formattted to ExFAT.

I have tried various recovery solutions provided here. Below, I provide two observations from those.

One recommended solution was to plug in the hard drive to Windows computer and simply run the "fix" option. This however changed a few things on the records of hard drive, and now it shows up under system information as being formated to MS-DOS FAT32 (even though it was formatted to ExFAT on Mac OS):

```
Media:
My Passport 2627:
  Capacity: 4 TB (4.000.752.599.040 bytes)
  Removable Media:  No
  BSD Name: disk4
  Logical Unit: 0
  Partition Map Type:   GPT (GUID Partition Table)
  S.M.A.R.T. status:    Verified
  USB Interface:    0
  Volumes:
EFI:
  Capacity: 209,7 MB (209.715.200 bytes)
  File System:  MS-DOS FAT32
  BSD Name: disk4s1
  Content:  EFI
  Volume UUID:  0E239BC6-F960-3107-89CF-1C97F78BB46B
disk4s2:
  Capacity: 4 TB (4.000.540.786.688 bytes)
  File System:  ExFAT
  BSD Name: disk4s2
  Content:  Microsoft Basic Data
```

When I ran `diskutils list` the driver shows up, however the provided command never gets exhausted until you provide `^C`, outputting the corresponding lines for the hard drive:

```
/dev/disk4 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *4.0 TB     disk4
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk4s1
   2:       Microsoft Basic Data                         4.0 TB     disk4s2
```

However, there is one last interesting point. The good old solution of running `sudo fsck_exfat -fyd disk4s2` is able to read the file system hierarchy correctly. It outputs the following lines (only the beginning part of the output is mentioned, in some parts it also outputs that the block is evicted):

```
fsck_exfat: Opened /dev/rdisk4s2 read-only
Opening /dev/rdisk4s2
** Checking volume.
** Checking main boot region.
7813556224 total sectors; 512 bytes per sector
FAT starts at sector 32768; size 131072 sectors
15260532 clusters starting at sector 163840; 262144 bytes per cluster
Root directory starts at cluster 11
Read      offset = 0x000001000000  length = 0x001000
** Checking system files.
Read      offset = 0x000005240000  length = 0x040000
** Volume name is My Passport.
Found active bitmap; first cluster 2, length 1907567
** Checking upper case translation table.
Read      offset = 0x000005200000  length = 0x040000
Found upcase table; starting cluster 10, length 5836
** Checking file system hierarchy.
Directory /
Directory /.Spotlight-V100
Directory /.fseventsd
Directory /.Trashes
Directory /Datasets
Directory /Videos
Directory /.TemporaryItems
Directory /Photos
Directory /+Backup
Directory /Side_Projects
Directory /Software
Directory /Music
Directory /Documents
Read      offset = 0x000005280000  length = 0x040000
...
```

It took me around 48 hours to exhaust this command. In the end, it was not able to fix the hard drive, and exited mentioning the process was not completed.

Is there any solution to recover some of the files from this drive even though the disk is not recoverable itself?

Edit: Even though the hard drive was formatted on Mac OS, I'm also open to solutions involving Linux or Windows.

Many thanks!

Comment: You should never try to fix in place if the first concern is the data.

Comment: There are commercial tools like GetDataBack, Windows based but might work for Apple.